# What are the common leadership styles in IT companies?

Tags: reference-request, io-psychology, leadership

I am writing a research paper on leadership styles in IT companies in X country. However, I cannot find a western literature on generalization of leadership styles exercised in IT companies, such as software companies for example. I am not interested in Project Management leadership styles as I have people of different titles in my sample. Please let me know if you have any suggestions on particular papers or authors who explored this question?

Comment: Maybe it's an idea to not look for scientific papers, but look for things like TED talks or posts/blogs on Linked-in. I can imagine enough people to have opinions about it.

Comment: There has been a lot written on this subject from the personality types point of view, like MBTI. Books like "type talk at work" come to mind. Upper leadership is frequently analyzed in these contexts

Comment: My guess would be that in most companies, anything resembling a style of leadership is purely accidental. Most people are not taught sufficient psychological background to even know that they have a choice about what they do. Management schools know about styles and results, but people have not applied the advice sufficiently well, from what I can see. I don't think IT companies are any better in that regard.

Comment: I agree that presumably there aren't any leadership styles which are typical for IT companies. Maybe it could be more fruitful to ask whether there are any recurring leadership problems related to typical tasks in IT companies? -- A rather spontaneous comment.